# Get the specific dates of moths considering a specific logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I am doing a code where I am stuck in a case :-

I am having a date : 31 jan 2014, and i want to get dates after every 1 month in a way
that next date should be 28 feb,2014 but because feb does not have 31 so I should get 28.
Than march is having 31 so it should have 31 .
basically a list which have

```
31 jan 2014
28 feb 2014
31 march 2014
30 april 2014
31 may 2014
```

Now if that date is : 29 jan 2014 than a list

```
29 jan 2014
28 feb 2014
29 march 2014
29 april 2014
29 may 2014
```

and i want to consider leap years to that too.

I was trying to use `addmonths(1)` function but in a loop when i try to add it

```
31 jan 2014, 28 feb 2014, 28 march 2014,28 april 2014,28 may 2014.
```

which was wrong.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to get the thing done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach works:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2014, 1, 31);
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(start.AddMonths(i));
```

Comment: Exactly. So instead of iterating `AddMonths(1)` many times, he should keep the start date and do `AddMonths(1)`, `AddMonths(2)`, `AddMonths(3)` etc. on the start date. **Edit:** Mathematically we see that the "axiom" `x.AddMonths(a).AddMonths(b) == x.AddMonths(a + b)` does not hold for `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

To get last date of the month you can use,

```
var thisMonthStart = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Today.Day);
var thisMonthEnd = thisMonthStart.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

So just give a try with.

```
AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

You can get last date of the next month.

Comment: I dont want to get the last day, Dynamically i want the dates to be of my logic I told above. see if date is 29 then i dont want last day I want 1 month to be added only

Comment: if 29 jan 2014 is first date then next would be 28 feb 2014, then 29 march .
if 31 jan 2014 is first date then next would be 28 feb 2014, then 31 march 2014.
if 25 jan 2014 is first date then next would be 25 feb 2014, then 25 march 2014.
last one can be done by addmonths(1) but not first two cases.

Comment: OK I give a hint... to get last date of the month. Just use AddSeconds(-1) to get last date of the month.. It's built in.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Calendar` class for adding months.

```
Calendar cal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
DateTime initialDT = new DateTime(2014,1,31,cal);
DateTime dt = cal.AddMonths(initialDT,1);
```

Comment: Do Increasing addmonths() in every iteration takes same time as of addmonths(1) ? if I am doing this way ?

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
static void Test5()
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2014, 1, 29);
    DateTime nextDate = start;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        nextDate = nextDate.AddMonths(1);

        if (start.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month))
        {
            // If the start date was the end of the month, then set the generated date to end of the month as well
            // e.g. 31/1 -> 28/2 -> 31/3 -> 30/4 -> 31/5 ... and so on
            int endDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(nextDate.Year, nextDate.Month);
            nextDate = new DateTime(nextDate.Year, nextDate.Month, endDay);
        }
        else
        {
            // Try to set the day to same as start day
            if (start.Day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(nextDate.Year, nextDate.Month))
            {
                nextDate = new DateTime(nextDate.Year, nextDate.Month, start.Day);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(nextDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }
}
```